# How can I create a formatted date field in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

In Javascript I want to be able to create a string for a date. I would like to use the format

```
dd-MMM-yyyy
```

- I would like the dd part to change between 1 and 29 every time I create the variable (I'm using a loop)
- the MMM is set to Jan
- the yyyy to 1999

Can someone help by giving me advice on how I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, can you post your "broken code"?

Comment: Yes, please share what applicable code you have so far. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: [How to search](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var formatted_date = Math.floor(Math.random() * 29) + 1 + '-Jan-1999';
  console.log(formatted_date);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do several things.

Check out [10 ways to format date and time using Javascript](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3).

[Another set of examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript).